# JavaFX Alerts and their size

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, alert

Recently, JavaFX introduced Alerts (Java 8u40).

Consider the code example below. How can I display a full message that is longer than just a few words? My messages (`contentText` property) get cut at the end with `...` and the Alert does not adjust its size properly in my opinion.

On my Linux machine with Oracle JDK 8u40, I only see the text `This is a long text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`, which is too short in some cases.

Of course, the user can resize the Alert window manually and the text will be displayed accordingly, but that is not user-friendly at all.

Edit: Screenshots for Windows 7 and Linux (JDK from Oracle): 
[image: Windows Alert]
[image: Linux Alert]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TestAlert extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        a.setTitle("My Title");
        a.setHeaderText("My Header Text");
        a.setResizable(true);
        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String content = String.format("Java: %s.\nThis is a long text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", version);
        a.setContentText(content);
        a.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: This issue seems to address what you are seeing: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095777.

It was supposedly fixed in 8u40, however, I still see the problem on CentOS with 8u45.

Comment: The bug is still present in java8u66 oracle linux(not openjdk).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33318661/179864

Comment: I have the same issue with Alert text in 2023 with Java 17 and JavaFX 19, when display scale is set to 150% or above on Windows 10. JavaFX likely doesn't allocate enough height for contentText in this case. The proposed solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/36938061/522578 worked well! Thank you.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I have made the following workaround:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Content here", ButtonType.OK);
alert.getDialogPane().setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
alert.show();
```

So the window will resize automatically according to the content.

Comment: Definitely the best answer: no magic numbers and just-one-loc tweak. I actually extended the Alert class adding this line to all the overridden constructors.

Comment: This works for the height but when I do the same with `setMinWidth`, it doesn't have an effect.

Comment: This only works for me if `alert.setResizable(true)` is called first (javafx 11, fedora 31).

Answer (score 20):

I have made the following workaround sometime ago:

```
Alert dialog = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
dialog.setHeaderText("Connection Failed");
dialog.setContentText(this.getException().getMessage());

//FIXME: Remove after release 8u40
dialog.setResizable(true);
dialog.getDialogPane().setPrefSize(480, 320);

dialog.showAndWait();
```

As you can see I just set resizable flag and set preferred size.

But this is strange because this bug [should be fixed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8097016) in 8u40. Are you using latest build of 8u40?

**UPDATE**:

Not fixed in 8u40. [Should be fixed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087981) later.

Comment: Yes, I am using 8u40. It seems to be a Linux issue. It shows the expected result on Windows. Don't know about OS X though. See also screenshots that I added, including the `java.version` property.

Comment: I think need to open new issue in JavaFX issue tracker. This is really seems like platform specific problem.

Comment: I can only confirm the problem. I am using a current Debian with jdk 8u40 installed. (+1 for the workaround!)

Comment: Confirming the linux issue as well. Ubuntu 15.04, jdk 8u40.

Comment: How does this workaround actually help? Because there is still no auto-resizing of the window if the message is too long. This only helps if you got some kind of big window where you can make sure all your messages fit in.

Comment: This issue is still present on 8u74

Comment: I had some dialogue size issues with alerts in Windows 10 (using 8u92), and this workaround fixed the problem.

Comment: Still present in JFX11!

Comment: Helpfully this also enables text wrapping

Answer (score 19):

Here is the better workaround without magic numbers, resizing etc.:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "content text");
alert.getDialogPane().getChildren().stream().filter(node -> node instanceof Label).forEach(node -> ((Label)node).setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE));
```

This solution works under Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: FYI: JavaFX is still [cut long text](http://i.imgur.com/pFawSxb.png) with this workaround :( Env: JDK 1.8.0_91, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @maxd, it's not obvious from your screenshot what was the complete text. i've put a much longer text before - and my solution worked

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is subclassing the Alert and applying desired style there, for example:

```
class SubAlert extends Alert {
    {
        setHeaderText("");
        getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add("some_stylesheet");
        getDialogPane().getStyleClass().add("style_class");
        getDialogPane().setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    }

    SubAlert(AlertType alertType) {
        super(alertType);
    }

    SubAlert(AlertType type, String title, String content) {
        super(type);
        setTitle(title);
        setContentText(content);
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to repeat actions for every Alert you create.

Answer (score 0):

Version 15 still only way to get around is:

```
dialog.setResizable(true);
dialog.getDialogPane().setPrefSize(377, 233);
Platform.runLater(() -> dialog.setResizable(false));
```