# JavaFX(Java 8 Update 40) Alert Dialog can't redraw and resize successfully

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, java-8, javafx-8

Java 8 Update 40 has added many new JavaFX UI controls including alert dialog. Before Java 8 Update 40 released, I used ControlsFX to show Dialogs in JavaFX. In ControlsFX, there is a Exception Dialog that can display exception's messages, but in Java 8 official dialogs, there is not any Exception Dialog. So, I want to make a Exception Dialog by myself with Java official dialogs.

I found  code below:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setTitle("Exception Dialog");
alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Exception Dialog");
alert.setContentText("Could not find file blabla.txt!");

Exception ex = new FileNotFoundException("Could not find file blabla.txt");

// Create expandable Exception.
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
ex.printStackTrace(pw);
String exceptionText = sw.toString();

Label label = new Label("The exception stacktrace was:");

TextArea textArea = new TextArea(exceptionText);
textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setWrapText(true);

textArea.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
textArea.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
GridPane.setVgrow(textArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
GridPane.setHgrow(textArea, Priority.ALWAYS);

GridPane expContent = new GridPane();
expContent.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
expContent.add(label, 0, 0);
expContent.add(textArea, 0, 1);

// Set expandable Exception into the dialog pane.
alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(expContent);
alert.showAndWait();
```

When the code was run, a dialog showed:

[image: no expand]

And then click the expand button, it should be showed as below:

[image: normal expand]

But in fact, it was:

[image: error expand]

This dialog has troubles in redraw and resize.

My OS is Linux Mint 17.1 64bits with MATE Desktop.

I don't know what causes this problem, maybe my X-Window has bugs, or maybe Java 8 has bugs, or maybe the code above does not strict enough. Did anybody encounter the same problem?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937392/javafx-alerts-and-their-size) is the same questions. Seems like this is platform specific problem. Try to create issue in JavaFX issue tracker.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered the same problem. My ugly hack was to add the following piece of code:

```
alert.getDialogPane().expandedProperty().addListener((l) -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        alert.getDialogPane().requestLayout();
        Stage stage = (Stage)alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
        stage.sizeToScene();
    });
});
```

Comment: if you don't use Platform.runLater resize wont work, this is important since i have tried before requestingLayout and sizeToScene but until i've made Platform.runLater nothing worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with the order in which you've written your code.

Try something like this:

```
GridPane expContent = new GridPane(); //Initialize the GridPane

//Add children
expContent.add(label, 0, 0);
expContent.add(textArea, 0, 1);

//set growth
GridPane.setVgrow(exceptionTextArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
GridPane.setHgrow(exceptionTextArea, Priority.ALWAYS);

//Add GridPane to Alert
alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(expContent);
```

Also, not sure if you need this:

```
expContent.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

as you've already setVGrowth