# JavaFX Alert truncates the message?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I noticed that if I try to show an `Alert` with a long message, it tends to get truncated (at a word boundary).

Example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AlertTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "this is a pretty long message that "
                + "should not be truncated in this alert window, no matter "
                + "how long it is").showAndWait();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This only displays "this is a pretty long message that should not be truncated" here.
What is the reason for the truncation, and how can I avoid it?

I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_60 in Linux.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it's only a Windows and Linux issue. It doesn't happen on MacOS. However I think this will fix it for you on all platforms.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setContentText("this is a pretty long message that "
                + "should not be truncated in this alert window, no matter "
                + "how long it is");
alert.getDialogPane().setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
alert.showAndWait();
```

Comment: I was revisiting this now, and figured out that the truncation happens because it's not allocating enough height for the content text, so it has no room to wrap. I couldn't find a way to fix the height issue, but then I saw your answer again, and found that it works very well, without using a custom content Node but just the built-in content Label (which I prefer). For the record, it looks like I still need to setContent with e.g. a new Label if I want to avoid wrapping (and make it adjust the width to fit the content) - just a different option that's available.

Comment: Still works in 2023 with JavaFX 20... why isn't this the default behavior? How is a customer supposed to report an error message if it's truncated?

Answer (score 3):

Try as

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.getDialogPane().setContent( new Text("this is a pretty long message that "
                + "should not be truncated in this alert window, no matter "
                + "how long it is"));
alert.showAndWait();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it makes the window very wide to fit the text on a single line, without wrapping. I found that I can solve that by calling `setWrappingWidth` on the `Text` object.

Comment: @aditsu, correct but your question was about avoiding the truncation and not about wrapping ;)

Comment: There are also a couple other formatting issues, but indeed, `setContent` is the key, the content node can be set to anything and adjusted at will. It would be nice if you could explain why it gets truncated in the original version; it seems that it's using a wrapped label but somehow the dialog is cropping it to just the first line?