# JavaFX Alert cannot fit content

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I've been trying to display a large string as an Alert unsuccessfully.

```
public void customAlert(String header, String body, ButtonType customBtn) {
    clearAlert();
    alert.setHeaderText(header);
    //alert.setContentText(body);
    String content = "";
    int counter = 1;

    int y=0;
    for (int x = 0; x < body.length(); ++x) {
     //    System.err.println("concat");
        if (x > counter * 50 && body.charAt(x) == ' ') {
          //  System.err.println("concat");
            ++counter;
            for (; y < x; ++y) {
                content.concat(Character.toString(body.charAt(y)));

            }
            content.concat(Character.toString('\n'));
           // System.err.println(content);
        }
    }
    alert.getDialogPane().setContent(new Label(content));

    alert.getDialogPane().setMaxWidth(500);

    if (customBtn != null) {
        alert.getButtonTypes().clear();
        alert.getButtonTypes().add(customBtn);
    }
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

First I tried with setContentText() and it didn't display the whole string. Then I used  alert.getDialogPane().setContent(new Label(body));  - but the alert box became wider than the screen size. Then I tried to filter the String added newline characters and to set maxWidth to the alert but the filtering didn't work.

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937392/javafx-alerts-and-their-size

Comment: Use exception dialog from [here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For long text, you’re better off presenting it in a TextArea:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea(text);
textArea.setPrefColumnCount(40);
textArea.setPrefRowCount(20);
textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setWrapText(true);
alert.getDialogPane().setContent(textArea);
```

Comment: This works but I am using one instance of Alert object for multiple alerts. When I want to remove the text area from dialog pane I cannot add any setContentText()

Comment: If you call `getDialogPane().setContent(null)` first, you can then call `setContentText`.  The rules for this precedence are described in the [documentation for contentText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html#contentTextProperty).