# JavaFX creates Alert dialog which is too small

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I'm using JavaFX 11.0.1 on Java 11 in Linux (KDE Plasma 5.12.2 on openSUSE Tumbleweed 20190314) to create an `Alert` dialog which should look like this:

[image: Screenshot showing the JavaFX Alert dialog as expected, large enough to make both the text and the OK button visible.]

But most of the time when an `Alert` is created and shown it is rendered far too small and looks like this:

[image: Screenshot showing the JavaFX Alert dialog so narrow that the only thing visible within it is half of the window's icon.]

About one in five times the `Alert` will display correctly. But the rest of the time the unhelpfully small version is shown instead.

There's nothing unusual about the code being used to display this dialog:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setTitle("Feature absent");
alert.setContentText(
    "Feature \"edit application settings\" has not been finished yet.");
alert.showAndWait();
```

and I've also tried [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937392/javafx-alerts-and-their-size) by adding the following to try to force the size to something useful:

```
alert.getDialogPane().setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
alert.getDialogPane().setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

but this gives exactly the same behaviour. (Note that even setting numeric values for the minimum width and height still don't fix the problem.)

Is this a known bug in JavaFX 11? Is there some known workaround which I can use to make sure the `Alert` dialogs are actually readable?

Comment: Can you try JavaFX 12? Can you try running with this option: `java -Djdk.gtk.version=2`?

Comment: I'm stuck with Java 11 for now. I did just try to force GTK version 2, but I'm using Maven and couldn't find a way to get custom VM arguments to be used when running the application.

Comment: You can keep using Java 11, but use JavaFX 12, as it includes some fixes for Linux. You can try the new `javafx-maven-plugin` from [here](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) instead of the `exec` plugin, and you could add that option.

Comment: I changed the JavaFX versions from 11 to 12-ea+14 and rebuilt. Same behaviour. I did just try the `javafx-maven-plugin` but it downloaded a lot of Google packages I was not expecting, and then failed with module visibility error (related to another dependency my application has).

Comment: JavaFX 12 has been already released. About the plugin, dependencies (modular and non-modular) should be managed by the plugin. Can you run `mvn -X clean javafx:run` and see if you spot a problem in the command line? If you have any issue that can be easily reproduced, could you file it [here](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/issues)?

Comment: Okay, I've raised [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/10) with my best guess as to the cause of the problem. But your project wiki doesn't make clear what is the benefit of using this custom plugin instead of the exec-maven-plugin. And why does it require so many Google and Android packages be downloaded when my project will have nothing to do with Android?

Comment: Thank you. You can see the list of dependencies of the plugin [here](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml). There is just a transitive dependency on Google's Guice. Might be related to your project?

Comment: And I just found a way to change between GTK 2 and 3 (in Netbeans the Tools/Options/Java/Maven/"Global Execution Options" can be used to brute-force the setting with the `-Djdk.gtk.version=2` or `-Djdk.gtk.version=3` argument. Same problem with the tiny `Alert` dialog in both GTK 2 and GTK 3, trying both JavaFX 11.0.2 and 12-ea+14 versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190146/discussion-between-bobulous-and-jose-pereda).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a known issue already [reported](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/222) on the exact same problem, affecting Linux with KDE. It can be traced back to this [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179073), affecting JavaFX 10 and 11.

The issue provides a workaround that works:

```
alert.setResizable(true);
alert.onShownProperty().addListener(e -> { 
    Platform.runLater(() -> alert.setResizable(false)); 
});
```

but that might leave the alert dialog resizable.

Comment: Thanks, José. It's not ideal that we need to do this, but at least this workaround does cause the `Alert` dialogs to appear correctly sized every time.

Comment: Indeed, the proper way would be fixing it. The related issue has some proposal on how to do it. Maybe you can check if that works (building OpenJFX is not that difficult) and report? It will increase the chances to getting it pushed upstream.