# Java FX Dialog "appears" with no size

Tags: kotlin, javafx, kde-plasma, xorg, javafx-11

I'm using JFX 11 on Fedora 33 (GNU/Linux) with the Xorg GUI server (v 1.20.11), creating a dialog thus (kotlin):

```
fun YNdialog (txt : String) : Boolean {
    val dlog = Dialog<ButtonType>()
    dlog.dialogPane.apply {
        contentText = txt
        buttonTypes.apply {
            add(ButtonType.OK)
            add(ButtonType.CANCEL)
        }
        minWidth = 200.0
        minHeight = 100.0
    }
    dlog.initOwner(theStage.scene.window)
    val r = dlog.showAndWait()
    return r.isPresent && r.get() == ButtonType.OK
}
```

This is called from an `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` associated with a `Button`:

```
if (YNdialog("hello world")) ...
```

There does seem to be a window created.  If I remove the `initOwner()` call, an icon for it appears in the desktop taskbar (KDE), allowing me to do things like move it, but "maximize" and "resize" are greyed out, and the mouse cursor appears to be dragging nothing, ie., it has no width or height.

With the `initOwner()` it does much the same thing, except it gets no taskbar icon.  Also, there is a visible vertical line one or two pixels thick where it should be (centered over the main window).  What's more interesting is *a second close button* appears in the titlebar of the main window:

[image]

This is not part of the javafx interface, but I've never seen the window manager (?) do this before.

Occasionally (maybe one in five or ten times) the dialog *does* appear, and curiously,
the close button there is offset with space for a second one:

[image]

When this happens and I can dismiss the dialog window, the second close button on the main window disappears.

## Using `Alert`

Replacing that function, etc. with:

```
Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "hello world").showAndWait() 
    .filter { res -> res == ButtonType.OK }                      
    .ifPresent { _ -> log.msg("ok!") }
```

The result is identical to the YNdialog with `initOwner()`.

Am I missing something here? I got all of this pretty much straight from [the docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html).  I have done custom popup windows (instantiated via `FXMLLoader`) and have not had any problem with that. Does this experience imply the dialog hierarchy is glitchy in this context and I should roll my own?

Comment: JavaFX 11 had a decent number of issues on Linux, if I remember correctly. I don't have a Linux machine so I never had direct experience with these issues, nor am I familiar with Linux. However, often I saw the solution was to tell JavaFX to use GTK 2 instead of GTK 3. This was done via a system property that I don't remember off the top of my head. Though consider trying a newer version of JavaFX (latest is 16) to see if your issue has been fixed already.

Comment: As an aside, `dlog.initOwner(theStage.scene.window)` can simply be `dlog.initOwner(theStage)` since `Stage` inherits from `Window`. Besides, `theStage.scene.window` will just give you the `theStage` instance. All of this assuming, of course, that `theStage` is a reference to a `javafx.stage.Stage`.

Comment: Hmmph, too bad, so far it has been relatively nice.   If I try 16 in the near future (I already have my own `PopupBase` as a workaround), I'll post whatever observation here.  I haven't tried looking for any existing bug reports yet.

Comment: Perhaps [initializing the stage style](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initStyle(javafx.stage.StageStyle)) (in addition to the owner and perhaps also the modality) before showing the dialog might help to work around some of the issues.

Comment: I'm guessing this is (at least partly) a duplicate of: [JavaFX creates Alert dialog which is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190380/javafx-creates-alert-dialog-which-is-too-small) which refers to a [bug report](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/222).  Comments on the bug are a bit vague but would appear to indicate that in recent JavaFX versions (e.g. 14+) the issue no longer occurs.  Linked duplicate also provides a work-around for earlier JavaFX versions.